# Silverlight media format compatibility

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am creating a web application using c# silverlight 5 that plays a brief video for the user to view.

What video formats are supported for c# Silverlight. The application will be accessed via Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE, and Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarized from MSDN article > [Supported Media Formats, Protocols, and Log Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) :

> MP3, ASF (WMA,WMV), MP4, 3GP, 3GP2

You can find detailed specification of each media format supported by `Silverlight` version of `MediaElement` in the link above.